# Bootstrap 4 Modal as Confirm Revisited

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to make a "flexible" confirm dialog with Bootstrap 4 as I do not want to hardcode each confirm modal / action on its own.

So, with a standard Modal like

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="msgModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="msgModalTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="msgModalBody">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Doch nicht</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnModelConfirmMessage">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the respective js-magic :D

```
function showConfirm(htmlInput,headerTxt, fun){
    $('#msgModalTitle').text(headerTxt);
    $('#msgModalBody').html(htmlInput);
    $('#msgModal').modal('show');
    $('#btnModelConfirmMessage').click(function () {
        fun();
        $('#msgModal').modal('hide');
    });
}
```

I thougth, that by sending the "action" part as function which will exceute as soon the "OK" button #btnModelConfirmMessage is clicked.

Works like a charm, BUT it has a major bug.

It seems that the event-handler stays on the modal, i.e. if I show and just hide the modal the OK button will fire the function twice.

Among others I found this post 
[Bootstrap modal firing up incrementing times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205912/bootstrap-modal-firing-up-incrementing-times)
where it suggest to move the click() event outside. I am sure this would work on that specific task, however I would lose the function.

So how can I unbind the handler using the `hide.bs.modal` event?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the jquery-doc the answer is fairly easy:

Change:

```
$('#btnModelConfirmMessage').on('click',function () {
        fun();
        $('#msgModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Then add a new call on the `hide.bs.modal` event

```
$('#msgModal').on('hide.bs.modal',function () {
        $('#btnModelConfirmMessage').off();
});
```

This removes the previously added handler, so we do not stack-up the events.

Hope someone will find this usefull :))

Cheers,
Daniel